# How can I refer to other urls' captured values in Django?

Tags: python, django

So, I am writing code with Python and Django (and other web dev requirements).

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path('wiki/<str:name>/', views.info, name="info"),
    path("create", views.create, name="create"),
    path("results", views.search, name="search"),
    path("wiki/<str:name>/edit", views.edit, name="edit")
]
```

The problem I am facing is that in `path("wiki/<str:name>/edit", views.edit, name="edit")`, I get an error:

> **NoReverseMatch at /wiki/Django/**>

> Reverse for 'edit' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['wiki/(?P[^/]+)/edit$']>

And I want to refer to the url in `path('wiki/<str:name>/', views.info, name="info")`

Please help me fix the error

Comment: Show your template that is throwing this issue and the views you have

Comment: The trailing `>` might be a problem

Comment: Also you should restrain from having similar names in your url path, try editing your `edit` url path to something like `"edit-wiki/<str:name>/"`

Comment: You are calling `url()` in a template and you are not providing a value for `name`.